# Add custom claim to id token or access token based on group membership existence on Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

I want to add a custom claim to the ID Token or access token on basis of the azure group user is part of.

Let me give an example. I want to create a custom claim named test. The value of this claim will be on basis of the azure group. If the user is part of group A, then the custom claim value will be A, If the user is part of group B, then the custom claim value will be B, and so on.

I am already using roles in a claim for some other thing, so can`t use that.

Comment: Please refer this document this may help you :https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/03/using-groups-claim-in-azure-active-directory/

Answer (score 0):

To enable the return of groups in a claim, there are two ways…

1. Use the application registration manifest by enabling the  **groupMembershipClaims**  property…
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest
2. or if it’s a SAML application, you can enable it though the SSO configuration.

The steps on enabling groups claim is outlined in the following article…
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims

Once enabled, groups will now be returned in the “groups” claim within a access token or ID token using OpenID Connect.

For more information you can refer this [***document***](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/03/using-groups-claim-in-azure-active-directory/)

Comment: I am not trying to add groups to user claim, instead I am planning to create custom claim and inject it to user claims on basis of AD group they are part of. It is similar to roles that we have in claims, instead of that we need custom created claim.